# jQuery/CSS - :hover enabled onClose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

My site has a jQuery plugin called Noty, 
it's a small notification window.
It shows under my header, but the header has a :hover pseudo class,
which makes it expand down, leaving the noty (that tells you to hover over the header) 
on top of it, and it looks like a mess.

The solution would be either adding ´.header:hover´ or changing ´.header´ to something like ´.headerhover´ that would relate with a pseudo class ´.headerhover:hover´.

I've already tried to make it, but the end result was crashing the whole header...

### jQuery/JavaScript:

```
  function generate(layout) {
      var n = noty({
          text: layout,
          type: 'information',
          text: 'Change your language here! Dismiss this by clicking.',
          dismissQueue: true,
          layout: layout,
          theme: 'defaultTheme'
      });
      console.log('html: ' + n.options.id);
  }

  function generateAll() {
      generate('top');
      generate('topCenter');
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {

      generateAll();

  });

  $.noty.top = {
      layout: 'top',
      theme: 'defaultTheme',
      type: 'information',
      text: '',
      dismissQueue: true, // If you want to use queue feature set this true
      template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span><div class="noty_close"></div></div>',
      animation: {
          open: {
              height: 'toggle'
          },
          close: {
              height: 'toggle'
          },
          easing: 'swing',
          speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
      },
      timeout: 500, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications
      force: false, // adds notification to the beginning of queue when set to true
      modal: false,
      maxVisible: 5, // you can set max visible notification for dismissQueue true option
      closeWith: ['click'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']
      callback: {
          onShow: function () {
              $(".header").removeClass("enabled");
          },
          afterShow: function () {
              $(".header").removeClass("enabled");
          },
          onClose: function () {
              $(".header").addClass("enabled");
          },
          afterClose: function () {
              $ ".header").addClass("enabled");
      }
  },
  buttons: false // an array of buttons
  };
```

### CSS:

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    height:70px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    background: rgb(210, 255, 82);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d2ff52', endColorstr='#91e842', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.header.enabled {
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    height:70px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    background: rgb(210, 255, 82);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(210, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d2ff52', endColorstr='#91e842', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.header.enabled:hover {
    height: 120px;
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
}
```

Detailed anserws please, so I can learn.

Comment: So...what is your question?

Comment: How can I get it working?

Comment: We can make detailled answers only if you describe your problem precisely

Comment: I did. Shortly: When I do ´onshow, aftershow etc.´ it won't work as it should and crashes my header div. It should work: When Noty is closed, enable header:hover.